# |R] Select multiple columns starting with the same pattern

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I have data frame df.
I want to select to the columns which names starts with q6, q7, q8, q9, q10 and q11.

If I write this expression it works :

`sub_df = df %>%`
`select( matches("^q(6|7|8|9|10|11)")`

How could I do using the : (seq) function ?
Something like
 `select( matches("^q(6:11)")`
or
`select( matches("^q(6-11)")`

But it does not work.
I am quite new using this regular expression.

How could I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use regex to match the 'q' from the start (`^`) of the string followed by the range of values `6-9` within `[]` or (`|`) the 1 followed by range of `[0-1]` at the end (`$`) of the string

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    select(matches('^q([6-9]|1[0-1])$'))
```

-output

```
          q6          q7          q8         q9        q10         q11
1 -0.07430856 -0.64859151 -0.11629639  0.6128514 -4.4695644  0.06735770
2 -0.60515695 -0.09411013 -0.94382724  1.5171225  0.3690450  0.01710596
3 -1.70964518 -0.08554095 -0.03373792  0.6573804  0.1692267 -0.34365937
4 -0.26869311  0.11953107 -0.58542756 -1.0741813 -1.8221903 -0.66789220
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(12 *4), ncol = 12, 
    dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("q", 1:12))))
```

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for.

Comment: I forgot the []
But I can't use the $ because the colnames are for exemple "q11_organic_waste"
should it be 
`df %>%
    select(matches('^q([6-9]|1[0-1])'))` ?

Comment: My whole formula, is
`select("city", matches("^q([6-9]|11|13|[18-36])")`, but it does not work.
It looks like I can't range from 18 to 36, I have to to several steps like you did for 10-11. 
The regex expression would be `select(matches("^q([6-9]|1[1,3,8,9]|2[1-9]|3[1-6])"))`
Am I write ?

Comment: @PaulDonadieu Then remove the `$` at the end because I thought the digits were the end.  Probably you want `_` instead of `$`

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% select(starts_with(paste("q",6:11, sep = "")))
```

Comment: vector of characters: ```> paste("q",6:11, sep = "")
[1] "q6"  "q7"  "q8"  "q9"  "q10" "q11"```

Comment: I also need  to add the q13, I wrote `df %>% select(starts_with(paste("q",6:11, sep = ""), starts_with("q13")))` . 
I have an error sayning "In if (ignore.case) { :
  la condition a une longueur > 1 et seul le premier élément est utilisé"

Can't I write several starts_with in the same select ?

Comment: cannot use several `starts_with`. first combine: c(6:11, 13) or for ex c(6:11, 13, 15:20);  `df %>% select(starts_with(paste("q",c(6:11,13), sep = "")))`